# How to open or create new window with MonoMac/Xamarin?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, xamarin, monomac

I have a Xamarin/MonoMac project with 2 windows. The main window opens, and functions like it should. However, I have a button that needs to open a second window (Lets call the first window "Main", and the second window "Second"). Both have their respective XIB files, and controller classes.

The button is set up in MainWindowController, and functions normally such that:

```
secondButton.Activated += (o, e) => {
     //Do stuff
}
```

Methods such as Console.WriteLine(); function as expected when the button is clicked.

The second window controller class is set up such that:

```
public partial class SecondWindowController : MonoMac.AppKit.NSWindowController {
    ...
}
```

What I need to do is cause secondButton to open an instance of SecondWindow upon being clicked, while passing the active instance of MainWindow to the SecondWindow constructor.

In C#.NET I would just use

```
SecondWindow sc = new SecondWindow(this);
sc.ShowDialog();
```

I can get SecondWindow to open, using this

```
NSWindowController nsc = new NSWindowController("SecondWindow", this);
nsc.ShowWindow(this);
```

But that causes an error stating

"Unknown window Class SecondWindow in Interface Builder file, creating a generic window instead."

The window shows as it should display, but no functions in SecondWindowController function, even if I run

```
nsc.AwakeFromNib();
```

directly after opening the window. No console output, and none of the buttons work.

How might I get the window to open, and function properly? If more information is needed, please let me know what I need to add, so I can get that to you.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I don't use Interface Builder, preferring to create and hook up my UI in code.  So I don't have a good answer for you.  But, for what it's worth, the error and behavior are consistent: when instantiating your window from the XIB, it can't find your SecondWindow class, and so it doesn't instantiate that controller (and none of the code in that controller applies).  I notice you're using SecondWindow in some places, and SecondWindowController elsewhere; check that you're being consistent.

Answer (score 0):

To get the window from the Storyboard you would need to use `NSStoryboard.InstantiateControllerWithIdentifier(string id) as NSWindowController`

Also you must set id as identifier for the window in the storyboard.